Identifying oven phase terminal?
Zanussi ZOPNA7KN - Earth is clearly marked.  Other two are unmarked.

Please use the Edit link's Mountain icon to add a readable picture of the terminals. Also. please identify where you are on this planet.

FWIW the instruction manual for the Zanussi ZOPNA7KN is laconic on the electrical installation instructions. But it does only discuss European gauges and wire colors. No sketch or picture of terminals, no instructions on which power/neutral wire goes where.

Things are a little different in the US/Canada because we have hot/hot/neutral/ground for most ovens for reasons. In any device that uses two hots and neutral it makes a big difference which wire is neutral. In addition, in the US/Canada neutral and ground are bonded, so for safety reasons a hot/neutral/ground device (i.e., only one "hot") should be wired correctly for safety.
In much of the rest of the world the connections for an oven are essentially hot/hot/ground. In some cases one of those hots will actually be neutral, in other cases it won't, depending on your house wiring. As a result, the instructions often refer to two "line" connections without specifying "hot" or "neutral" because it just doesn't matter, as long as the voltage between the two "line" connections is correct for the appliance.
